# Separate Android APKs based on third-party library's native code for each CPU architecture

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using the Realm library for Android, which is released with separate native shared libraries for each CPU architecture, including armeabi, x86, etc.  In order to avoid bundling them all into one large APK and wasting space, I'd like to make separate APKs with the matching shared library, for each architecture.

According to [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits), by adding the following into my build.gradle:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'x86'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

I should get 5 separate APK files - which I do.  But they're all the same file size!
Do split APKs only work for code build into the app itself, and not third-party libraries?

Comment: Does the generated APK contain all the ABIs?

Comment: 'universal' prop true will copy everything everywhere. defeats the purpose

Comment: How exactly are you integrating the native libraries from Realm ? can you share gradle configuration files ? btw the universal prop generate an _additional_ apk with all the ABIs, it doesn't defeat the purpose.